# Counting the amount of a specific object in 2D Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, counter, getter

In a checkers game for my CS class I have run into trouble with counting how many of a specific color piece are on the board.
Here is the getter method:

```
 public int getCheckersBlue()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y <= 12; y++)
        {
            if(c[x][y].equals(Color.BLUE))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

The constructor for c:

```
private CheckersBoard[][] c = new CheckersBoard[8][8];
```

Whenever trying to run the game in Greenfoot a null pointer exception is thrown even when the code compiles. Even with everything declared, everything has something it's pointing to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Note that with the `c` constructor you are creating an _array of array of `CheckersBoard` objects_, which is probably not what you want

Comment: 1- Nullpointer :the c is seems to be null at positions [0][0], [0][1] ..etc. 2- the code is doesn't look right as you only initialising array of 8 but you want to iterate 12 times so you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if you fix the null pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two major problems in your code:

1. You're iterating over 0-8 elements for x and 0-12 for y, but in declaration you has 0-7 for x and the same for y
2. `NullPointerException`. This caused because array declaration will fill your array with null values, so you're comparing `null` with `Color.Blue` which is incorrect.

With the both fixes code will look like this

```
public int getCheckersBlue()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            if(Color.BLUE.equals(c[x][y]))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

But I think it's still logically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few of things...

1. You are iterating through 12 every time in the inner loop when it should be 8.
2. Color.Blue is a `JavaFX Paint`, I believe. This is not really what you should be using. Unless you have made your own `Enumeration type` of Color, you should do so. Here is a [link](https://crunchify.com/why-and-for-what-should-i-use-enum-java-enum-examples/) for how to do so with relevant examples.
3. You are checking equality of two different types: `CheckersBoard` and `Color`. You should have a `CheckersBoard.getSpace(x, y).getColor()` or `CheckersBoard.getSpace(x, y).getOccupancy()` (which should have a *NoOccupancy* option) if we want to be completely logistically sound with our naming.